# Execute an SQL query depending on the parameters of a pandas dataframe

Tags: sql, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have a pandas data frame called final_data that looks like this

| cust_id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-30 |
| 10002 | 2022-02-01 | 2022-02-30 |
| 10003 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-30 |
| 10004 | 2022-03-01 | 2022-03-30 |
| 10005 | 2022-02-01 | 2022-02-30 |

I have another table in my sql database called penalties that looks like this

| cust_id | level1_pen | level_2_pen | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | 1 | 4 | 2022-01-01 |
| 10001 | 1 | 1 | 2022-01-02 |
| 10001 | 0 | 1 | 2022-01-03 |
| 10002 | 1 | 1 | 2022-01-01 |
| 10002 | 5 | 0 | 2022-02-01 |
| 10002 | 4 | 0 | 2022-02-04 |
| 10003 | 1 | 6 | 2022-01-02 |

I want the final_data frame to look like this where it aggregates the data from the penalties table in SQL database based on the cust_id, start_date and end_date

| cust_id | start_date | end_date | total_penalties |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-30 | 8 |
| 10002 | 2022-02-01 | 2022-02-30 | 9 |
| 10003 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-30 | 7 |

How do I combine a lambda function for each row where it aggregates the data from the SQL query based on the cust_id, start_date, and end_date variables from each row of the pandas dataframe

Answer (score 1):

Suppose

df = final_data table

df2 = penalties table

you can get the final_data frame that you want using this query:

```
SELECT
  df.cust_id,
  df.start_date,
  df.end_date,
  SUM(df2.level1_pen + df2.level_2_pen) as total_penalties
FROM
  df
  LEFT JOIN df2 ON df.cust_id = df2.cust_id
    AND df2.date BETWEEN df.start_date AND df.end_date
GROUP BY
  df.cust_id,
  df.start_date,
  df.end_date;
```